# How to correctly get user information in React/Redux/OIDC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, openid-connect

Fairly new to OIDC - I've done a bit of work with it in the past, but I wouldn't call myself an expert by any means.

I am trying to use OIDC in a react app using the oidc-client-js and redux-oidc libraries (along with the redux-oidc-example as an example)

I'm getting this error:

Error: No matching state found in storage
    at eval (oidc-client.min.js:1011)

Now I've looked around for a solution to this, and this is the closest I'm seeing to my problem, but I still don't find anything here clearly explaining anything:

https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/648

Here's my callback function:

```
const successCallback = (user) => {
  this.props.dispatch(push("/settings"))
};


class CallbackPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <CallbackComponent
        userManager={userManager}
        successCallback={successCallback}
        errorCallback={error => {
          //this.props.dispatch(push("/chat"));
          console.error(error);
        }}
        >
        <div>Redirecting TEST...</div>
      </CallbackComponent>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(CallbackPage);
```

Before commenting out the props.dispatch in the error callback, it was a never-ending loop. Now it just freezes on the callback page with whatever I put in the error callback.

I won't put my full userManager settings, as that seems like it would be excessive, but here are some of the main highlights:

```
{
    "authority": "https://subdomain.appname.com/auth/realms/appname/",
    "client_id": "appname-app",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:3001/callback",
    "response_type": "code",
    "extraQueryParams": {"kc_idp_hint": "google"},
    "loadUserInfo": true,
    "scope": ["openid", "profile", "email"]
}
```

I'm not sure what else would be helpful to anyone troubleshooting it - I can give my store.js information or my main application index.js if needed.

Comment: Can you trhow in the method inside the class and try it out please?

Answer (score 1):

Scope paramenter for user meneger should be space separated string and not an array.

Example: `'openid profile email'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
class CallbackPage extends React.Component {

successCallback = (user) => {
  this.props.dispatch(push("/settings"))
};

  render() {
    return (
      <CallbackComponent
        userManager={userManager}
        successCallback={this.successCallback}
        errorCallback={error => {
          //this.props.dispatch(push("/chat"));
          console.error(error);
        }}
        >
        <div>Redirecting TEST...</div>
      </CallbackComponent>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(CallbackPage);
```

Comment: Ah, no, absolutely no change

Comment: It's presumably related to the problem listed on this page - https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/648 - I am just not sure what "looks like you're using a routing path for your redirect uri. you might need to manually parse the #/hash out of the URL and pass in just the protocol response params into the signinRedirectCalback." means or how I should implement it.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander I havent used props.dispatch. I trigger an action from the connect method. https://github.com/a2441918/my-address-book/blob/master/client/src/components/LeftNav/LeftNavPage.jsx and https://github.com/a2441918/my-address-book/blob/master/client/src/components/LeftNav/LeftNav.jsx

Comment: I don't think it's related to the dispatch method. It's related to some sort of header or information that I am not passing in my urls, at some point in the process. It's an OIDC issue that I'm not understanding.